# how to build a javascript library?

Tags: javascript, build

I find a bug in [this repo](https://github.com/ali-sdk/ali-oss), and want to modify the source code and build that, so I can test it. but I am not very familiar with the tool-chain (stuff like npm or bower) that building this project, so How to build that? I mean create a new `dist/aliyun-oss-sdk.min.js`, based on my modification?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Projects using npm usually define scripts in the `package.json` you can run to execute common tasks (e.g. test, build, etc.). Having a look at the `package.json` you can see that it has a `build-dist` script. You can run it with:

```
npm run build-dist
```

There are also instructions in the README https://github.com/ali-sdk/ali-oss#how-to-build